# d3 text only appears when added to a group. Why?

Tags: d3.js

I have appended some text to a map I am working on in d3, here is my code:

```
    countriesGroup = svg
        .append("g")
        .attr("id", "map");

    //add background
    countriesGroup.append('rect')
        .attr("x", 0)
        .attr("y", 0)
        .attr("width", w)
        .attr("height", h);

    //Draw countries
    countries = countriesGroup.selectAll("path")
        .data(j.features)
        .enter()
        ...Draw country borders

    //Create Timer Text
    countriesGroup.append("text") <-----This worked
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + w/2 + "," + h/2 + ")")
        .style("fill", "#ff0000")
        .text("This is a test");

    //Create Timer Text
    svg.append("text") <-----This didn't
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + w/2 + "," + h/2 + ")")
        .style("fill", "#ff0000")
        .text("This is a test");
```

I initially tried appending the `Timer text` directly to `svg` but that did not work. When I later tried appending it directly to the `countriesGroup` group, this worked. How come the text was only able to render when appended to the group, but not when appended directly to the svg?

Comment: Can you show how you create/select the svg and does the text appear in the DOM (but behind something perhaps)? Because appending text to an svg should work: https://jsfiddle.net/e2ghar5j/1

Comment: If you append the text directly to the svg, you need to specify x and y coordinates to draw the text where you expect it to appear (appending to the countriesGroup ensures that the text is drawn at that element's coordinates).